# Sum of to times using javascript

Tags: javascript

can anyone tell me how to do sum of two time using javascript (momentjs) for exemple the sum of:

> 2:44:56 and 2:50:56

i tried that but doesnt work:

```
2:44:56 + 2:50:56
```

any suggestions please??

Comment: [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/)

Comment: how to do that with moment.js

Comment: What is wrong with `t = new Date(t1.getTime() + t2.getTime())` ?

Comment: i have 2:44:56 + 2:50:56 not a  date object

Comment: @jrook It lacks a library. Everything in JS must use a library.

Comment: You can do it with a duration. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/

Comment: @imsiimsi, then please revise the question and state your constraints and requirements clearly.

Comment: @imsiimsi what result are you expecting to get? `5:35:52`

Comment: What does this have to do wih Angular?

Comment: @LazarLjubenović it makes it _dynamic_ :3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add 2 times together JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25764553/add-2-times-together-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

Momentjs has a [duration](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) object that can be used to add or subtract two or more timespans.

```
const a = moment.duration('02:44:56');
const b = moment.duration('02:50:56');

const c = a.add(b);

console.log(c.hours() );
console.log(c.minutes() );
console.log(c.seconds() );
```

Comment: This is a neat way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this. Use add method on moment object and pass your data.

```
let x = moment({  
         hours:'2', 
         minutes:'44',
         seconds:'56'})
       .add({ 
         hours:'2',
         minutes:'50', 
         seconds:'56' })
 console.log(x)
```

or dynamically pass data

```
let time = {
   hours: 2,
   minutes:44, 
   seconds: 56
}
let time2 = {
   hours: 2,
   minutes:50, 
   seconds: 56
}
let y = moment(time)
         .add(time2)
console.log(y)
```

Comment: the time is dynamic..i cant do that

Comment: you can pass variable instead of strings :-)

Comment: moment({  
         hours: time.hours, 
         minutes: time.minutes,
         seconds: time.seconds})

Comment: Please do not post code-only answers. Take time to explain what's happening to a reader can learn from it.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović Like this??

Comment: Um moment(time1).add(time2) ??

Comment: @Jonasw :-)after this you make me laugh. i will go to sleep soon

Comment: it gives me NAN

Answer (score 0):

One could add the seconds, then calculate the carry value and add that to the sum of minutes and so on. That can be easily done with reduce:

```
function sum(date1, date2){
  date1 = date1.split(":");
  date2 = date2.split(":");
  const result = [];

  date1.reduceRight((carry,num, index) => {
    const max = [24,60,60][index];
    const add =  +date2[index];
    result.unshift( (+num+add+carry) % max );
    return Math.floor( (+num + add + carry) / max );
  },0);

 return result.join(":");
}

console.log(
  sum("2:44:56" , "2:50:56" )
);
```

[Try it](http://jsbin.com/danomecepu/edit?console)

Comment: Please do not post code-only answers. Take time to explain what's happening to a reader can learn from it.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović He does try to explain it, albeit in 1.5 lines.

Answer (score 0):

#### The code:

```
var t1 = moment('2:44:56', 'HH:mm:ss');
var t2 = '2:50:56';
var parsed_t2 = t2.split(':') // [2, 50, 56]

var r = t1.add({
  hours: parsed_t2[0], // 2
  minutes: parsed_t2[1], // 50
  seconds: parsed_t2[2], // 56
});
```

#### The process:

1. Parse the string as a moment object (helping it with defining the format we're using;
2. Split the time we want to add to the **t1** by using the `split()` function effectively splitting our **t2** into an array where we have `[hours, minutes, seconds]`
3. Add the the times together using the moments `add()` method.

---

### [Working example](http://jsbin.com/coranor/15/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 0):

**moment()** function takes **hours, minutes, seconds** as arguments and return a moment object which has a **add()** method that also can take **hours, minutes, seconds** as arguments and return total times.

Try **addTimes(time1, time2)**

```
function addTimes(time1, time2) {
   let [hours1, minutes1, seconds1] = time1.split(':');
   let [hours2, minutes2, seconds2] = time2.split(':');
   return moment({ hours: hours1, minutes: minutes1, seconds: seconds1 })
       .add({ hours: hours2, minutes: minutes2, seconds: seconds2 })
       .format('h:mm:ss');
}

console.log(addTimes('2:44:56', '2:50:56'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Good old JS solution:

```js
var base = new Date(0);
var t1 = new Date(base);
var t2 = new Date(base);
t1.setUTCHours(2,45,50);
t2.setUTCHours(2,50,50);
var t = new Date(t1.getTime() + t2.getTime() - base.getTime());

result = t.getUTCHours() + ":" + t.getUTCMinutes() +":" + t.getUTCSeconds();
console.log(result);
```

Note that JS automatically converts time of the day to GMT timezone hence we need to use UTC version of time functions.