# MongoDB: Aggregate query to sum duration field

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregate

I have set of records from where I need to sum up duration to be displayed

**Records**

```
[{   
  id:"1",
  duration:"07:30:00"
},
{   
  id:"1",
  duration:"07:30:00"
}
{   
  id:"2",
  duration:"07:30:00"
}]
```

**Output**

```
[{
  _id: 1,
  totalDuration: "15:00"
},{
  _id: 2,
  totalDuration: "07:30"
}]
```

Answer (score 2):

From MongoDB version >= 4.4 you can use the [$function](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/) operator to define custom functions to implement behavior not supported by the MongoDB Query Language. Logic to add two time-data in `HH:MM:SS` format is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25764553/add-2-times-together-javascript#answer-54237524).

So try this query:

```js
db.testCollection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$id",
            times: { $push: "$duration" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            totalDuration: {
                $function: {
                    body: function(times) {
                        let hours = 0;
                        let minutes = 0;
                        let seconds = 0;

                        for (let i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
                            let values = times[i].split(":");

                            hours += parseInt(values[0]);
                            minutes += parseInt(values[1]);
                            seconds += parseInt(values[2]);
                        }

                        let realHrs = hours + Math.floor(minutes / 60);
                        let realMins = (minutes % 60) + Math.floor(seconds / 60);
                        let realSecs = seconds % 60;

                        return realHrs + ":" + realMins + ":" + realSecs
                    },
                    args: ["$times"],
                    lang: "js"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { _id: 1 }
    }
]);
```

Output

```js
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "totalDuration" : "15:6:12"
},

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "2",
    "totalDuration" : "7:30:0"
}
```

Data in `testCollection` collection:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "id" : "1",
    "duration" : "07:30:30"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "id" : "1",
    "duration" : "07:35:42"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "id" : "2",
    "duration" : "07:30:00"
}
```

Comment: If you are using this solution the plz thoroughly test the logic inside the `$function` `body` for edge cases. I have not tested it thoroughly.

Comment: What is your MongoDB version?

Comment: my mongodb version is  3.6

Answer (score 1):

There is no any straight way to do this in mongodb, You can use [$function](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/) operator starting from MongoDB v4.4 you can write custom logic in JS syntax,

---

Second option you can do custom logic using mongodb arithmetic operators,

- `$split` to split duration string using `":"` to array and set it to `time` variable in `$let`
- `$arrayElemAt` to get specific element from array, we are taking `hour` and `minute` from 0 and 1 position
- `$toInt` to convert string to integer
- check condition if minute is `00` then return o otherwise 0.5
- `$add` to sum `hour` and `minute`
- `$group` by `id` and sum `duration`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      duration: {
        $let: {
          vars: {
            time: { $split: ["$duration", ":"] }
          },
          in: {
            $add: [
              { $toInt: { $arrayElemAt: ["$$time", 0] } },
              {
                $cond: [
                  { $eq: [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$$time", 1] }, "00"] },
                  0,
                  0.5
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$id",
      duration: { $sum: "$duration" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1TJtxVRUcqM)

The query will result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "duration": 15
  },
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "duration": 7.5
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $addFields: {
         duration: {
            $let: {
               vars: { time: { $split: ["$duration", ":"] } },
               in: {
                  $dateFromParts: {
                     year: 1970, month: 1, day: 1,
                     hour: { $toInt: { $arrayElemAt: ["$$time", 0] } },
                     minute: { $toInt: { $arrayElemAt: ["$$time", 1] } },
                     second: { $toInt: { $arrayElemAt: ["$$time", 2] } }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $group: { _id: "$id", duration: { $sum: { $toLong: "$duration" } } } },
   {
      $set: {
         duration: {
            $dateToString: {
               date: {
                  $dateFromParts: {
                     year: 1970, month: 1, day: 1, millisecond: "$duration"
                  }
               },
               format: "%H:%M:%S"
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

However, if the duration is longer than 24 hours then it does not work anymore. But you may add `{ $dayOfYear: <dateExpression> }` to the output, then the duration may go up to one year.